# java script text based game and objects

Tags: javascript, sorting, oop, object

I am writing a text based game where I want users to be able to manipulate any item.

I want the user to be able to say, for example, "I throw the bottle of oil at the monster."
Now when this happens [throw] will be an action, [bottle of oil] is an inventory item with the property [contains oil], and the monster will be the nearest monster in the room unless specified further.

Code needs to analyze the various properties of all these things and then pick actions that cause those things to interact.

When i write the Game story code it will be like follows

> *room.darkroom.1 "wake up" [...] everything appears blurry, the voice sounds strange as if echoing down a long tunnel. From what you can see you can tell [you are in a dark room] your vision blurs from white to dark. [pc is inside very dark room. Inside this room everything is hidden in darkness. The northern wall has a locked thick wooden door. the southern wall has a barrel full of oil containing a bottle of oil. In the eastern side of the room are 2 medium sized crates one crate contains flint and rusty dagger. In the western side of the room a [small window] */room.darkroom.1

The script will take all those words and apply properties to them randomizing certain elements that are left unstated. So if you then say "chair" it will go to the chair properties and randomly assign unstated properties. One property of chair will be material. If its not stated that its an oak chair then the script should pick from any of the material properties and assign them. This new chair will pick up a few properties and be saved for future reference on the database with all properties.

Another property would be an action. A chair would not necessarily have an action .. but it might break. The script needs to know if the chair is breakable. But I am thinking that could be nested into another property like [toughness].

Many things will have many of the same properties: chair, night stand, table would all be similar in many ways. But they would also have different outcomes depending on the actions applied to them.

How do I specify for instance when "broken" contains chair legs and scrap material? The chair legs and the scrap material would both need to inherit the properties of the chair that was destroyed, such as oak / flammable / breakable. Obviously, as stated before, it might not have to inherit flammable or breakable if oak is the part that holds that value.

I want to make it easy to access the array that stores properties and that might include a script that effects behavior and descriptions of things.

I started to just create a keyed array which would be looped through... But now I am thinking that I should utilize the object based element of JavaScript.

Here is what i have started to do but I stopped right away:

```js
var language = {
    // key    currentmodifyers   possible modifyers   action/condition description of item

    item: ";medium,material;;its a thing thats not a person",
    chair: "item,chair_Legs;;pile_of.@scraps.collection.chairlegx3/broken,@[chair ]scraps/destroyed; and someone could sit on it. ",
    chair_leg:"item,blunt,light,"
}
```

I have so many definitions to write so it would be a shame to start writing it all and then have to do it over when I discover the best way.

I am looking at various ways to build objects in JavaScript, but would like the best way from someone experienced.

Understanding the complexity of my problem, what is the best way to store and apply properties?

Comment: Please rephrase your question in a more concise format. As it is now, you have five paragraphs that do not seem related to your question, which I assume is "What is the best way to store and apply properties". Additionally, there is no "best" way to create / use javascript objects.

Comment: Way too much to read here. Please scale immediate problem down to some sort of quick overview. Remove all the meaningless preamble also

Comment: If I knew the answer I wouldn't be asking it. You need to understand the complexity of what I am trying to accomplish in order to suggest the best method to store variables.  If you dont have time to read a few paragraphs you will not understand what my problem is. I appreciate the helpful comments but I am not looking for a fly by comment on proper syntax but a thoughtful and experienced statement regarding the best method of structure based on my needs. .

Comment: I changed my question at the end per suggestion.

Comment: Adding context to a question is great. Adding code to a question is necessary. Adding a project spec, however, is not fine. This is a Q&A site--someone else might come along with your specific question, and the answer here might help them. No one will come along and find the minute details of your project helpful, nor will it assist anyone in answering your question, because it is so long that _you cannot even find the question_. If your question is "what is the best way to store and apply properties", the answer is _any_. Any method at all is fine. There is no "best" way.

Comment: [This might help you](http://eloquentjavascript.net/).

Comment: How to Ask

Is your question about programming?

We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
Provide details. Share your research.
this was the statement by this website. My question can be answered but it has to be answered by someone with experience. it cant be answered by googling it which is why I am asking here. If it makes anyone uncomfortable I'm sorry. but this is a question of structure. I do not know what way is the best way to store properties so they can be easily accessed and yet not redundant at the same time. There are plenty of questions on this site

Comment: @PeterSMcIntyre the problem is not only that the text is long, you obviously didn't pay enough attention to the text. There are lots of typos / small mistakes and repetitions, so it is hard to follow your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two good thoughts in your question:

> But now I am thinking that I should utilize the object based element of JavaScript.

You definitely need to use objects instead of arrays, the OOP ideas can be directly applied to your descriptions.
Some objects are composed of smaller parts (the "composition" in OOP) and some inherit properties of other objects (the "inheritance").

So you could have some base `Item` class which defines basic operations and properties for all objects (like they have different properties and can do some things).

Then you can add objects like `StaticItem` (will be base for chairs, night stands, etc) and `LiveBeeing` (monsters, etc).
And now you can actually create the `Chair` (pseudocode):

```
StaticItem extends Item
    this.material = oak // oak is an object of OakMaterial

    // is this static item flamable?
    this.isFlamable = function() {
        // we "redirect" flamability detection to the material
        return this.material.flamable();
    }


Chair extends Static
    // break this chair!
    this.break = function() {
        // when it is broken we return a HeapOfCrap, it is a 
        // Static subclass which contains some sub-items
        // In this case the heap contains 4 chair legs of the
        // same material as the chair
        return HeapOfCrap([
            new ChairLeg(this.material), new ChairLeg(this.material),
            new ChairLeg(this.material), new ChairLeg(this.material)
        ])
    }
```

And so on, you need to plan you object structure carefully and there is a good field to apply some of the [design patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612).

The example above is just what came in my mind immediately, while actual design should take much more time and thinking.

The second good thought in your question is about the huge amount of work:

> I have so many definitions to write so it would be a shame to start writing it all and then have to do it over when I discover the best way.

You absolutely right here, would you select to use objects or arrays, or anything else - don't try to describe all your game right away.

Select few basic elements, like "Room", "Door", "Chair", "Monster", "Player" and try to code the minimal game with only these elements.

Play with the structure to find the good design and once you are sure it is good - go on and add more elements to the game.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. I also purchased that book you referenced.  I have been using object oriented code JavaScript and c# for 12 years as a hobby and it seems this is the first time my project has been big enough for me to have to use oop. One other question.. lets say I have items, animals, conditions to cover my entire list of game names. Apart from looping through them like Items{list{list{{list{}}}}. is there an easier way to loop through all variables to compare them to commands?

Comment: @PeterSMcIntyre Great! IMO this book is the best one to actually learn how OOP works in practice. Regarding your question - I think you can try Composite pattern to structure the objects and Visitor or Command to match commands to objects, check the book for details.